# Появляется SocketException при подключении

Tags: c#

Каждые 10 секунд подключаюсь к сервису на удаленном компьютере, получаю нужные мне данные и закрываю соединение. Но периодически появляется исключение:

*"SocketException: Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера...."*

Из-за этого программа на некоторое время подвисает, что не очень приятно. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно правильно обработать исключение чтобы избавиться от подвисаний и программа работала стабильно? Брандмауэры везде полностью отключены

```
try
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/api/xxxxx/xxx");
                    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                    string line = "";
                    string value = line;
                    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                        {
                            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                            {
                                value = line;
                            }
                        }

                    }              
                    response.Close();
}
catch
{
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте выставить свойство Timeout у реквеста
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Нужно освобождать _все_ ресурсы. Оберните `WebResponse` в `using`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Очень странная реализация, в читаете строку из `Stream` и при этом если в нем более одной строки, то перезаписываете постоянно эту строку следующей, и так далее до окончания стрима.

2) Следующая проблема, вы не освобождаете ресурсы. Для `IDisposable` классов `WebRequest` и `WebResponse` нужно либо применять `using`, либо вызывать `Dispose()`. Подробнее читайте в [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects).

3) Потом, [`WebRequest`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest?view=netframework-4.8) устарел, и очень давно.

> Не рекомендуется использовать `WebRequest` или производные классы для новой разработки. Вместо этого используйте класс [`System.Net.Http.HttpClient`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.8).

4) Чтобы все не подвисало, пока идет загрузка из сети, следует использовать асинхронность. Вот пример асинхронного получения строчки по сети через HTTP(S).

Вы не указали, WPF у вас, WinForms, или консоль, поэтому попробую дать простое и универсальное решение.

```csharp
// HttpClient создается один раз на все время работы программы.
private static HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

А использовать `HttpClient` можно из обычного синхронного кода например так. Все методы `HttpClient` асинхронные, ну потому что синхронные запросы в сеть - это бессмысленно.

```csharp
Task.Run(async () =>
{
    string result = await client.GetStringAsync("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/api/xxxxx/xxx");
    // ответ получен, сделайте здесь что-то с result.
});
```

или из асинхронного обработчика события (допустим, у вас WPF)

```csharp
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string result = await client.GetStringAsync("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/api/xxxxx/xxx");
    // ответ получен, сделайте здесь что-то с result
}
```

Не забудьте обработать исключения, так как в процессе получения данных от сервера они могут возникнуть.

Comment: С исключениями будет весело.

Comment: @Qwertiy это уже другая история. :) Тем более, человек знаком с `try {} catch {}`.

Comment: Всё равно весело когда поведение зависти от конфига и теоретически может меняться в зависимости от компа, на котором запущена программа.

Comment: @Qwertiy это такой же сферический пример в вакууме, как и в вопросе, только рабочий. Я не против отвечать на дополнительные вопросы в комментариях, если они вдруг возникнут. Дописал в конец ответа намёк, ваше замечание справедливо.

Comment: Ну так я ж не против, даже плюсик поставил. Просто не смог молча пройти)))

Comment: Зачем `Task.Run` если метод и так асинхронный?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov чтобы вставить код можно было после `await`.

Comment: @aepot Спасибо за Ваш развернутый ответ. Воспользовался Вашим советом, убрал WebRequest, WebResponse и все остальное что было с ними связано. Теперь использую HttpClient, создал асинхронный метод в котором уже работаю с result. Периодически проскакивает исключение "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException", но я его обрабатываю и проблема с подвисаниями программы исчезла. Спасибо за помощь!